# query from database into JSON string view in google charts

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, google-visualization

Currently developing a website where I query data from a mysql database and encode it to JSON string, I want to view the data using the google charts and tables.

At the moment I can't view the data in the tables but the JSON string output seems to be correct.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function drawVisualization() {
        var jsonData = null;
        var json = $.ajax({
          url: "dataTableViewDaily.php", // make this url point to the data file
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: (
              function(data){
                jsonData = data;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Create and draw the visualization.
      visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
      visualization.draw(data, null);
              })
        }).responseText;
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

However I have echo the JSONString on this url:
dataTableViewDaily.php

Would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: It looks like your JSON is valid, but the dataTableViewDaily.php script might be outputting more than the JSON.  If any HTML is leaking into the JSON, then it would fail.

Comment: I believe that is the problem as well, since I get an error of Invalid JSON. But when I call the dataTableViewDaily.php and echo the string the jsonObj is correct, but when I call it to the script I get this error. Where can the problem be from? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your jsonData into tables which Google Charts api can understand.

Here is a simple javascript snippet from a project that I have been working on recently.

```
//Assuming jsonData has a json array : customerList
var jsonData = {
                  "count":2,
                  "customerList":[
                      {"customerName":"gupta","customerID":"you@example.com"},
                      {"customerName":"neetesh","customerID":"me@example.com"}
                    ]
                };
c = jsonData.customerList; 
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 's.no.');
data.addColumn('string', 'Customer Name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Customer email ID');
data.addRows(c.length);
for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
{
    data.setCell(i, 0, i)
    data.setCell(i, 1, c[i].customerID);
    data.setCell(i, 2, c[i].customerName);
}
visualization = new google.visualization.Table(
                            document.getElementById('table'));
visualization.draw(data, null);
```

Comment: the dataTableViewDaily.php is echo a JSON string which the google charts api understand, I have this JSON as a result.

{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Date","type":"string"},{"id":"B","label":"User","type":"string"},{"id":"C","label":"Cement Brand","type":"string"},{"id":"D","label":"Volume","type":"string"},{"id":"E","label":"Type","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"08-06-2013"},{"v":"razee.hj@gmail.com"},{"v":"Muthana"},{"v":"27"},{"v":"Local Plant"}]},{"c":[{"v":"08-06-2013"},{"v":"razee.hj@gmail.com"},{"v":"Samawa"},{"v":"28"},{"v":"Local Plant"}]}]}

Comment: It seems to be a problem when I echo the JSON string in the dataTableViewDaily.php as it can't read the output from there into the javascript because the JSON string is correct. However this is the part of the code I have in that file:

$jsonObj = json_encode($table);

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');


echo $jsonObj;

Comment: Your JSON data is perfect. Use firebug or chrome developers tools to see what exactly is returned from your server.

Comment: I receive Invalid JSON string now but even if when I call the dataTableViewDaily.php file alone it seems to be valid JSON string. So i am very confused by this problem,

Comment: I hope you have done this. Add this line in your success function: `console.log(jsonData);` and see the output in Chrome -> inspect element -> console tab and check if that was the json you wanted.